# Looking for a Hindi fantasy/horror novel name 'Pishacho ki mallika'

Tags: story-identification, vampire

It's a pulp fiction novel (likes of *Surender Mohan Pathak*) that I read when I was 7-12 year old of age (I'm 26 now), so around 1997-2002.

There is no information on the Internet remotely related to it. I guess the author is not well known (the same could be said for majority of Indian literature). I hope someone here could help me find it or at least tell me the author's name.

Here is the story that I vaguely remember:

It is about a witch who practices black magic and becomes semi-immortal. She needs to eat/drink the flesh of a young man to remain youthful, but whenever she tries to kill an innocent person, a holy priest appears and stops her. So her personal ghoul (she has 40 of them, all made of dirt and sewage, appearing at her command; as you learn more black magic you get more ghouls) suggests her to kill only evil men so that the priest does not appear to stop her. So she start killing evil men but she wants to get rid of the priest and do whatever she wants. In the end she does the penance and gets the ability to turn anyone into stone when she puts her hand on their head. The priest tricks her into dance and she puts her own hand on her head, turning her into a stone.

Comment: You might try posting your question [on GoodReads](https://www.goodreads.com/group/show/185-what-s-the-name-of-that-book) as well. I've had some good results there.

Comment: Thanx @JoeL. I will try there.

Comment: If the novel was published in Hindi, was the title in Hindi too? Including the original title in Devanagari script might help people search for it.